# How to implement buttons in QTreeView similar to macOS plist editor?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

How would one implement behaviour similar to a plist editor that macOS uses which can be seen in the following GIF:

[image]

So, when one hovers over a row, buttons "add" and "remove" appear. Also, when one selects a row they stay visible.

I was thinking of some kind of a hidden column with those buttons and for the simplicity's sake all the columns would be of a fixed width.

I don't think the exact behaviour can be implemented with that text hiding and all (or it would be too much of a hassle), but for the simpler case that I need, would it be possible to implement some kind of a hidden column with buttons and is that a good approach?

Comment: You should go with MVC approach, then your delegate will be responsible of showing what you want in its paint method.

Comment: Yes of course, since I am using QTreeView, I have to use MVC approach (or MV approach to be more precise) and I know that I will have to override paint(). I am asking for concrete guidelines, how would one do it? Another hidden column where buttons will be? Or I can put buttons in a row and somehow align them right? Or some third way I didn't think of?

Comment: The way I am used to, is reimplementing QStyledItemDelegate and in the paint method  call QApplication::style()->drawControl(...) to draw any kind of widget at the wanted position (this seems OK for your use case)